# If $L/K$ is normal extension $\Rightarrow K_s/K$ is normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field, separable-extension

If is $L/K$ a normal extension, then it follows that $K_s/K$ is a normal extension.

Definition of normal extension:

Let $L/K$ be an algebraic extension and $\overline{L}$ be a algebraic closure of $L$, the following are equivalent:

1. L is a splitting field of $p \in K[x]$ over $K$
2. For every injective $K-$Homomorphism $\phi: L \rightarrow \overline {L} $ is $\phi(L)=L$
3. Every irreducible polynomial from $K[x]$ with a root in $L$, splits over $L$

If an algebraic field extension $L/K$ satisfies one of the above condition (and thus all of the above conditions), then it is called a normal extension.

Let $L/K$ be an algebraic extension. Then $K_s:=\{a \in L : a \text{ is separable over } K \}$

An Element $a \in L$ is called separable if its minimal polynomial $m(a,K)$ is separable over $K$ and $a$ is algebraic over $K$.
A polynomial $P \in K[x]$ is called separable, if every irreducible factor of $P$ in a splitting field of $P$ over $K$ only has simple roots.

My attempt:
I think the easiest approach would be to show that every irreducible polynomial from $K[x]$ with a root in $K_s$ splits over $K_s$.
So let $p \in K[x]$ be irreducible and assume that $p$ has a root in $K_s$.
Thus, we can write $p(x)=q(x)(x-r)$ for some polynomial $q$

Now there are two options:
$q$ has root in $K_s$

$q$ has no root in $K_s$

Assume $q$ has no root in $K_s$
Now I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Assume $p\in K[x]$ is irreducible and has a root $\alpha\in K_s$. Then we know that $p$ splits in $L[x]$. Well, can you show that all the other roots of $p$ belong to $K_s$ as well? (i.e that they are all separable over$K$)

Comment: I know that $p \ in K[x]$ irreducible is separable $\Leftrightarrow $ if $p$ has only simple roots in its splitting field. This is the case iff $p' \neq 0$. So $\frac{d}{dx} q(x)(x-r)$= $\underset{\neq 0}{\underbrace{q(x)}}+\underset{\neq 0}{\underbrace{(x-r)}}q'(x) \neq 0$.
Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, but irrelevant. You don't know almost anything about $p$, so the derivative will not help you. But I claim you can still say $p$ is separable.

Comment: @Mark How I can't figure it out

Comment: Because $\alpha\in K_s$, which means it is separable over $K$. And $p$ is irreducible, so (assuming it is monic, which we can to do without loss of generality) it is its minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much.